# How to install Kali Tools on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS 64-bit?

Tags: 20.04, kali-linux-tools

I had just got my first Lenovo T14 with Ubuntu OS, and I want to install Kali tools following this guide: https://www.tecmint.com/install-kali-linux-tools-using-katoolin-on-ubuntu-debian/.

I made `/usr/bin/katoolin` executable by running the command:

```
# chmod +x /usr/bin/katoolin
```

but I keep getting an error:

```
unable to execute ./katoolin: No such file or directory
```

I'm sure there is a mistake somewhere along the lines, but couldn't figured it out. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

I used

Comment: You only use `./` before the command if you are in the same directory.  If you are outside of the directory but the file is in the path then it is just the command `katoolin`.

Comment: Here is directory info:  ubuntu:/usr/bin$ ls -l /usr/bin/katoolin 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 51401 Dec 29 14:41 /usr/bin/katoolin
ubuntu:/usr/bin$ ./katoolin 
bash: ./katoolin: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: You are attempting a tutorial written in the time of Ubuntu 14.04 on a much more recent system. You are ready to break your system if you push this further.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that! I was actually thinking the same way - one of the reason I came to the community for further guidance.  Do you know recent tutorial for the new systems?